How if condition works in SAS background?
How do if works if i write the code below:
data B;
  h= 1;
  D="M";
run;

data c;
 set b;
 length nn $30;
 type = vtype(H);

 if type eq "N" then  nn=put(h,best.);
 else if type eq "C" then nn= h;
 else call missing(nn);
run;

here I am getting the note " Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by:"
as per my understanding the if condition will only go to the part nn=h when the condition if type eq "C" satisfies. But I can see that, this is not the case here as the note comes because of that statement.
see below code:
data a;
  D= '1';
  output; 
  D=""; 
  output;
run;

data r;
  set A;
  if not missing(D) then a=input(D,best.);
  else call missing(D);
run;

Here the condition if not missing(D) is checked and then only the futher conditions have been fulfilled. and no note is produced as well
also, my code doesn't produce the note if I use %if instead of if and use it inside a macro.

That type conversion message is generated when the data step is compiled.  Not when it it executes.
The statement
nn = h ;

implies a type conversion when NN is character and H is numeric.  It does not matter to the compiler if the code ever executes or not.
If you want to convert a variable of unknown type to character why not just use the CATS() function?
 74         data c;
 75          set b;
 76          length n1 n2 $32;
 77          n1 = cats(h);
 78          n2 = cats(d);
 79         run;
 
 NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.B.
 NOTE: The data set WORK.C has 1 observations and 4 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds

